# Definition of a Knot

Tags: definition, knot-theory

I was reading this website: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/23/stemkoski/knots/page1.html and I was confused by the definition of knot provided. The definition is as follows.

A $\bf{knot}$ $K$ is the image of a continuous function $f : \left[0, 1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$, $f$ restricted to $[0, 1)$ is injective and $\frac{df}{dt} \neq \vec{0}$ for any $t \in \left[0, 1\right]$. My issue with this definition of a knot is that knots are equivalent if they are ambient isotopic. The definition of ambient isotopy from the wikipedia page starts: "Let $N$ and $M$ be manifolds and $g$ and $h$ be embeddings of $N$ in $M$." Well any knot as defined above cannot be an embedding since the map $f$ is not injective since $f(0) = f(1)$ by definition.

So if we define knots as above:

1. Is the definition incorrect for a knot from this website?
2. Is there a different way that we should define equivalence?
3. Parameterizations of knots seem like they could be nice to work with so is there a way to make this definition work?

Comment: A knot is an embedding of $S^1$ into $S^3$. Not sure why they define it in such an abnormal way to be honest. The condition that the curve have the same start and endpoint is sort of like interpreting the domain $[0,1]$ as $[0,1]$/0~1, but not exactly.

Comment: The book "On Knots" by Kaufman uses the def'n  as given in the comment by AJ Stas, and states that Knot Theory is the study of the different ways that $S^1$ can be homeomorphically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A knot isn't an embedding of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R^3$, it's an embedding of $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)\cong\mathbb S^1$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Given a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^3$ with $f(0)=f(1)$, there is a continuous map $\tilde f:\mathbb S^1\to\mathbb R^3$ with $f=\tilde f\circ\pi$ where $\pi:[0,1]\to\mathbb S^1$ is the quotient map. This map $\tilde f$ gives the embedding, not $f$. Maybe this is what confused you?